# What are the 'n', 'l', '3pm' sections of the manual for?

Tags: perl, man, posix, standard

An excerpt from the `man man` page:

> The default action is to search in all  of  the  available sections following a pre-defined order ("1 n l 8 3 2 3posix 3pm 3perl 5 4 9 6 7" by default)

What are the `n`, `l` and `3pm` sections of the manual for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `3pm` section is not used anymore. It is defined as manual pages concerning modul packages of perl in an old version of the Debian Perl Policy, noteably in version 1.2. [Here](http://www.fifi.org/doc/debian-policy/perl-policy.html/index.html#contents) is a site where you can read that old deprecated policy (see §3.1 and §1.4). In the [latest Debian Perl Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/perl-policy/) it is defined in §2.4 that module manual pages should be installed in section `3perl` now.

In the [standards manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/standards.7.html) page you see that "POSIX.1-2001, SUSv3" standard has defined manual page sections called `1p` and `3p`. That is also mentioned at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections), that `p` is a subsection that describes POSIX specifications. `3p` is also an abbreviation of `3posix`, which means the same.

The sections `n` and `l` seem to appear only in [IBMs AIX](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds3/man.htm?cp=ssw_aix_53%2F1-2-0-12-14&lang=en). `n` specifies "new" and `l` specifies "local".

Local (`l`) manual pages describe usage policies, administrative contacts, special local software, and other information unique to this particular installation. New (`n`) manual pages are for newly installed software. They stay for an amount of time in `n` before they get moved to their permanent section. In Linux those two section and also the `o` section (old) are [deprecated](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Man-Page/q2.html).

Note, that `n` in [Mac OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/manpages.5.html) can also be the section for Tcl/Tk functions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does Linux put pages for Tcl commands (f.i. `itcl(n)`)?

Comment: At my debian box it's `3itcl`, but I think it could also be `n` on some systems.